# Using Swift Package Manager (SPM) for Existing [iPhone App] XCode Project (Having Swift + Objective C Files)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am trying to create Library which I can use into my Existing XCode Project (iOS App). 
I am aware that Swift Package Manager now support generating Xcode project with command

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

But I am not creating new project. In my existing project having Objective C & Swift Files, How can I use newly created Swift Package?

How to add Package.swift file to my current Project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use SPM right now within iOS apps.

You can use it in hosted environments for example if you are hosting a web application with Vapor on a Mac or on Linux.

Comment: According to this...https://gist.github.com/nathanborror/4ecb16bcb1ae0bd11e7eed043c6cd8bd... its possible

Comment: I've created scripts and Xcode templates which allow for that: https://swiftxcode.github.io

Answer (score 6):

To use Swift (v4) Package Manager with iOS you have to jump through a couple of hoops.

Basically,

1. Make a Package.swift for your app's dependencies
2. Use the output of `swift package generate-xcodeproj`, modified to work with iOS, as a subproject of your main App xcodeproj
3. Link your dependency Frameworks as you normally would

I have an [example with reproduction steps](https://github.com/j-channings/swift-package-manager-ios)

Comment: You don't need to generage an xcodeproj anymore, I explained more about the folder hierarchy in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64758546/can-i-specify-a-platform-target-when-running-swift-test-from-the-cli/65256621#65256621

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers (Josh, T. Swifty) are outdated. You don't need to generate an `xcodeproj` based off a `Package.swift`, in fact, `swift package generate-xcodeproj` is a deprecated command.

If you're making an app, just add your Swift Package in Xcode (in the `project` > `Swift Packages` tab). Only create a `Swift.package` if you're making an executable or library, instead of an application for iOS, macOS, etc.

The guide is: [Adding Package Dependencies to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app)