# Can I specify a platform target when running swift test from the CLI?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift-package-manager

My `Package.swift` looks something like

```
let package = Package(
  name: "MyPackage",
  platforms: [
    .iOS(.v13)
  ],
  products: [
    .library(
      name: "MyPackage",
      targets: ["MyPackage"])
  ],
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit.git", from: "5.0.0"),
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "MyPackage",
      dependencies: [
        "SnapKit",
      ]),
    .testTarget(
      name: "MyPackageTests",
      dependencies: ["MyPackage"])
  ]
)
```

When I run `swift test` I get

```
error: the library 'MyPackage' requires macos 10.10, but depends on the product 'SnapKit' \
which requires macos 10.12; consider changing the library 'SurfUIKit' to require macos 10.12 \
or later, or the product 'SnapKit' to require macos 10.10 or earlier.
```

Why is swift running tests for macos that is not listed as a supported platform? Can I get swift to run the tests for iOS, ideally specifying some version target? What alternative do I have using xcode in the CLI?

Answer (score 16):

The trick is:

- you think that `.iOS(...)` is here to restrict the compilation to only one platform
- while it actually is a line used to specify `what minimum version` is going to be supported by your product for this platform

It does not say: `only compile for .iOS X.y`, but `.iOS min version is X.y`

SPM is a tool for `Swift first`, thus wants to build for `all~ platforms`, and has currently no way of using a ~system only parameter~ (I know me sad too).

---

Now if you want to have an iOS only Package it's still possible but [you'll have to compil through **xcodebuild** commands](https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-and-library-unit-testing/26255/20) (and you don't need a xcodeproj file for that).

`// Compile and test on iOS simulator`

`xcodebuild -list`

`xcodebuild -scheme <scheme> -destination 'generic/platform=iOS'`

`xcodebuild -scheme <scheme> -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11'`

`xcodebuild -scheme <scheme> test -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11'`

---

[SPM documentation usage about "Depending on Apple modules"](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#depending-on-apple-modules)

---

From my experience I would also say that you could have a folder hierarchy as follow (with xCode 12):

| `Root Project folder/`

- `Source/` // folder of your sources
- `Example/` // create an xcodeproj in it
- `Tests/` // Your tests files ~
- `YourPackage.xcworkspace`

  - add the `root folder` in it to be able to **access your Package targets**
  - add your example project (and add your Package to its dependencies)
  - finally create a **new scheme** in which you select the **Test target** of your package

Now you're all setup to develop your Package in parallele with your example and tests.

And remember that Swift Package Manager currently (12/2020) has no parameter to only build on one platform.

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Thanks it's a real bummer that `platforms` doesn't mean the list of platform one want to support...

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, and more than a bummer, it's a missleading thing.. How many people assumed the same way really :/ (btw if it answered the question feel free to mark it done o/)